# Delphi Cross Platform Socket Issue

Tags: android, sockets, delphi, firemonkey

First of all I am trying to make a Client/Server:
Server is an app in a PC (VCL).
Client is an android App.

When the server is online, once i open the client its connects normally,
When the server is offline, I need to auto re-connect to the server but in this case the client is stuck at this procedure and doesn't get out of it:

```
FClientSocket.Connect(string.Empty, '192.168.1.155'+#0, string.Empty, 4851);
```

trying to free the socket gives an error..
trying to free the thread doesn't get freed..
i did everything but nothing worked ..
My code so far (stripped):

```
uses ..System.Net.Socket..    
 ..   
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  FClientSocket: TSocket;
  FThread, RThread: TThread;
  Connected : Boolean = False;

Procedure Connect;
begin
  FClientSocket := TSocket.Create(TSocketType.TCP);
  FClientSocket.Connect(string.Empty, '192.168.1.155'+#0, string.Empty, 4851);
  Connected := True;
end;

Procedure Disconnect();
Begin
  Connected := False;
  if FClientSocket <> nil then
    FClientSocket.Free;
end;

Procedure TForm1.SocketConnect;
begin
  Connected := False;
  //Connect to VCL server
  RThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    Connect;
  end);
  RThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  RThread.Start;
  Sleep(500);

  While Connected do
  begin
    // Receive the message from the VCL server
    // ..
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    SocketConnect;
  end);
  FThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FClientSocket <> nil then
  Begin
    FClientSocket.Free;
  end;
  if FThread <> nil then
  Begin
    FThread.OnTerminate := nil;
    FThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
    FThread.Terminate;
    FThread.WaitFor;
    FreeAndnil(FThread);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Re `procedure Disconnect`: (1) `if FClientSocket <> nil then FClientSocket.Free;` is exactly equivalent to `FClientSocket.Free` because `X.Free` effectively is `if X <> nil then X.Destroy`. (2) It is a good idea to set `FClientSocket` to `nil` when it has been freed, for otherwise you have a dangling pointer. (3) You can combine freeing and niling: `FreeAndNil(FClientSocket)`.

Comment: Anonymous threads are already set to `FreeOnTerminate=True` by default. But more importantly, using an anonymous thread just to call `Connect()` and then `Sleep()`'ing expecting `Connected=True` to happen in the meantime is just plain wrong design. You are using 2 anonymous threads when 1 will suffice. Get `Connect()` out of `CreateAnonymousThread()`, since the calling code is already in a thread, just let `Connect` block that thread until it exits. And put a `try..except` around `Connect()` so you can handle retries.

Comment: That being said, do you have the same problem if you use `BeginConnect()` instead of `Connect()`?  Have you tried Indy's `TIdTCPClient` yet, and does it suffer from the same problem with sticking?